# Converting string to integer is throwing an error at me :(

Tags: java

Im trying to convert a string to an integer as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
public class Assignment4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // introduce program
        System.out.println("\n========================");
        System.out.println("Card Number Verification");
        System.out.println("========================\n");
        System.out.println("Enter 16 digit card number (no spaces): ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // initialize scanner

        // intialize any relevant variables
        int sum = 0; // sum for all digits in card number
        int new_card_number; // relevant variable

        String card_string = sc.nextLine(); //get users card number
        int length = card_string.length(); // get length of number

        // verify that it is 16 numeric characters
        if (length != 16 || card_string.matches("\\d+") == false)       
        {   
            System.out.println("Restart the program and enter a valid card    number.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int card_number = Integer.parseInt(card_string.trim());
        new_card_number = card_number; // ensures card_number doesnt change
        while (length > 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (new_card_number % 10);
            new_card_number = (new_card_number - (new_card_number % 10)) / 10;
            length--;
            System.out.println(new_card_number + sum);

        }
    }
}
```

and heres the error I'm getting:

```
========================
Card Number Verification
========================

Enter 16 digit card number (no spaces): 
1234123412341234
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1234123412341234"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at Assignment4.main(Assignment4.java:28)
```

I've tried using the trim option or just entering the string variable directly as 'Integer.parseInt(card_string)'.  Why am I still receiving this error?

Comment: Note that you can check that the card number is 16 digits long in one check `if (!card_string.matches("\\d{16}")) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [JLS : 4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> [...]
>
> - For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive

---

You're exceeding the `int` value limit here

```
Integer.parseInt(card_string.trim());
```

---

A nice solution would be to use `BigInteger` when working with very large numbers.

```
BigInteger myBigNumber = new BigInteger(card_string.trim());
```

Many operations are possible as `sum`, `multiply`, etc...

Source : ***[BigInteger JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)***

---

The other solution would be to use `long` instead of `int`. It is limited but the limit is quite high, check it out below.

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> [...]
>
> For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive

Comment: Just to point out, `BigInteger` isn't a great choice here, because of all of the arithmetic operations which are performed in the existing code - each operation you perform on it requires a new `BigInteger` instance to be created, since they are immutable. It's not terminally bad; just a bit wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

`int` max size is 2,147,483,647. You are trying to parse much bigger number 1,234,123,412,341,234.

You can use `long` instead of `int`

```
long card_number = Long.parseLong(card_string.trim());
```

Comment: is there some way to get around this? im trying to get a card number from the user and eventually add the digits up to verify if it's a accurate number

Comment: @JordanPagni I added solution.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you are getting this exception because the card number is a larger number than can be represented by an `int`.

You appear simply to be summing the digits of the card number, apparently going in reverse (although that's only relevant if you're printing something out whilst summing).

You don't need to parse the entire string as digits to do this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = card_number.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  sum += Character.getNumericValue(card_number.charAt(i));
  System.out.println(card_number.substring(0, i) + sum);
}
```

(Note that the `trim` is unnecessary, as you've already checked that it's only digits)

Without the `println`, you can more easily (/naturally) do:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < card_number.length(); ++i) {
  sum += Character.getNumericValue(card_number.charAt(i));
}
```